# Can't see any C# Add Wizard Method in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I can't see it as mentioned here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/dll12222005064058am/dll.aspx

Do I have to activate somehow ?

Comment: That blog entry was done in 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you are referring is using VS 2003. If you want to achieve the same in VS2005/2008 you can right click on the class in the Class View and choose View [Class Diagram](http://www.developingfor.net/visual-studio/visual-studio-2008-class-diagram.html). There you can select to create methods, properties, fields and events.

Answer (score 1):

The article you point to is nine years old and a lot has changed since then. I suggest you take a look at [recent documentation from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version of .net as what is referenced in that article?  The article dates to 2000... Which is 1.0